# Why does gtk(mm) css font-size crash on RPi but not on x86

Tags: raspbian

I have a small application that displays some data on a Pi. I Wrote it in C++ and build it in a Raspbian chroot using qemu-arm-static. I copied the binary to the Pi (which runs the same Raspbian as the chroot is based on), but on the Pi my program crashes with the following message:

```
(ZmqSubscriber:2602): glibmm-WARNING **: Glib::Error::throw_exception():
  unknown error domain 'gtk-css-provider-error-quark': throwing generic Glib::Error exception

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Glib::Error'
Aborted
```

This seems to come from the font-size lines in my css (`font-size: 12pt;`, also tried `px` units), because if I remove those lines my program runs and displays fine, but with wrong font-sizes. I can safely build and run the application on my x86 laptop, and it doesn't give any errors at all.

Does anyone have a clue to why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

- Check the library version(s) you're using. Maybe the older versions do not support units (?)
- Try without the unit: `font-size: 12;`